# Why do new terminals in Awesome spawn with SHLVL>1?

Tags: bash, awesome

I have a [`PS1`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/6967a8b1523c8c2828c4c6ee23372a2320bb0d79/.bashrc#L76-L79) which shows the SHLVL if it's not 1 to quickly see if I'm in a subshell. This works as expected when using GNOME, but when I spawn a new terminal in Awesome WM (<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>) it always starts with `SHLVL=2` or higher. Is this normal?

This is directly related to the number of times I have restarted Awesome (<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or `pkill -HUP awesome`). Is there some way to avoid spawning new shells when restarting?

[These](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=commitdiff;h=30aeb3f3114eb9c7e4cd8c3f91ac046f6060a778) [commits](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=commitdiff;h=b0ab2d419370b727d9151baf9b5ff606dbe74564) seem to be relevant, since Awesome ends up running something like `$SHELL -c ...` on `HUP`, but I don't know enough C to fix it.

My `/bin/sh` is `dash` and my login shell is `bash`.

[Reported the issue](https://awesome.naquadah.org/bugs/index.php?do=details&task_id=1105&project=1&opened=826).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand the why, but I don't have a complete fix.

The behavior of `SHLVL` depends on the shell. In dash and ksh (both pdksh and ksh93), only interactive instances increment `SHLVL`. In bash and zsh, all instances increment `SHLVL`, even `bash -c …`.

If you observed a change in behavior after [this patch](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=commitdiff;h=b0ab2d419370b727d9151baf9b5ff606dbe74564), it's likely that your `/bin/sh` is dash and your `$SHELL` is bash. Before , awesome was executing `/bin/sh -c …` which didn't change `SHLVL`. After the patch, it is now executing `$SHELL -c …`, i.e. `bash -c …`, which increments `SHLVL`.

You could cheat by changing `SHLVL` inside Awesome. Hook into the startup code to decrease `SHLVL` by 1. I'm pretty sure this is possible without recompiling the C code, though I don't know the Lua code.

Comment: I don't know what the behavior was before the patch, because I just started using Awesome after using Gnome for at least a year.