# Launch Gnome Terminal with Shell Level 1?

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Gnome allows the default Terminal Profile to be changed for new Terminals created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

But what if I want to:

Create a new terminal with a specific profile from the command line

```
gnome-terminal --profile=<profile_name> --working-directory=<full_path>
```

`echo $SHLVL` produces `2`.

Is there a way to do this where the `SHLVL` is `1`?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63788/

Comment: @JdeBP thanks, that was interesting. Along the right path, similar to automorphic's soluiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set SHLVL manually for that command to compensate for the erroneous +1:

```
SHLVL=0 gnome-terminal
```

Opens a new window. Then

```
echo $SHLVL
1
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).